# ManyToMany relation between News and Users

Tags: php, symfony

I have an Entity called `News` which contains a `ManyToMany` relation with the `User` Entity. This means that an article can be written by multiple authors.

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="GW2\UserBundle\Entity\User")
*/
private $authors;
```

The problem is that I would like to add authors dynamically in the form I use to add `News`, but I don't know how to **store the data**, and **keep the relation** between my two Entities. The number of authors is not fixed, and not limited.

I did some research about the `collection` type and added it to my `NewsType`, but I don't really know how to use it.

---

**Edit:** Here is my current NewsType (without the authors `collection`):

```
<?php
namespace GW2\SiteBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class NewsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', 'text', array('error_bubbling' => true))
            ->add('introduction', 'textarea', array('attr' => array('class' => 'input-block-level redactor_content'), 'error_bubbling' => true))
            ->add('content', 'textarea', array('attr' => array('class' => 'input-block-level redactor_content'), 'error_bubbling' => true))
            ->add('publication', 'checkbox', array('required' => false, 'error_bubbling' => true))
            ->add('categories', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'GW2SiteBundle:Category',
                'property' => 'name',
                'required' => false,
                'multiple' => true
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'GW2\SiteBundle\Entity\News'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'gw2_sitebundle_newstype';
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your NewsType and we'll help you out from there

Comment: @ThomasPotaire I edited with my NewsType.

Comment: Alright and you know how to save the categories right? It should be the same idea

Comment: I know how to save categories, because it's an Entity field. Concerning the users, I don't want to list them all like an Entity field would do, I would like to add each author in a text field. And as the number of authors is undefined, the number of fields is undefined too. I don't know how to save them...

Comment: did you try implementing the [adding-and-removing solution](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#adding-and-removing-items)?

Comment: I tried to use the form_type in FOSUB (http://yoone.eu/url/c3) but it allows to specify only one user per news, so can I use the `collection` type to add several users per news?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed my problem by adding a `collection` with the FOSUB type, while specifying the `allow_add` and `allow_delete` options.

```
->add('authors', 'collection', array(
    'type'=> 'fos_user_username',
    'allow_add' => true,
    'allow_delete' => true
))
```

Then I added the [adding-removing solution](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#adding-and-removing-items) with JavaScript to dynamically add fields in the form (thanks to [Thomas Potaire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2155387/thomas-potaire)).